# Remotely execute command via vagrant ssh

Tags: ssh, virtual-machine, remote-access, vagrant

Using vagrant ssh I'm able to ssh into VM(ubuntu). But once I ssh into VM, I want to go to a directory on VM's Desktop and execute a command. In short, I want to achieve the following:

a) ssh into VM

b) Go to a directory on VM's Desktop

c) Execute a command (for eg. list all the hidden files in this directory/install a software in this directory)

I tried using vagrant ssh -c "cd /Desktop".

This gives me a message:-- Connection to 127.0.0.1 closed.

Is there any way I can go to folder and execute command using vagrant ssh?

Answer (score 0):

This is normal. The `cd` command is not giving any output. If you would do for example `vagrant ssh -c "ls"` you would get the directory content, and afterwards the Connection closed message.

So `vagrant ssh -c "..."` is the way to go!

Answer (score 0):

```
vagrant ssh -c 'cd /Directory && <my cmd here>'
```